# Rails 4.1.8 "blog" posts not saving text or title when using strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm a long time lurker who's google-fu is failing him today. I've been learning to use Rails using a video series that was created before Rails 4 came out. As such, the lectures use the attr_accessibly mass assignments. I've been attempting to convert this to working strong parameters, but am having an issue actually saving info to my PostgreSQL database.

Basically, I should go to localhost:3000/new, add a title, body, and category, then submit. This goes off without a hitch, but my /posts (which lists all posts) shows the title as /posts/(whatever row number it's on), does not display the text, and only shows a date-time stamp when clicking on the post (url). Also, my database is only storing a post/row number.

Note: I am aware of things like ActiveAdmin, but would prefer to learn how to make/save posts manually before using such modules.

Here is the post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
   @posts = Post.all
end

def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
  @category = Category.all
end

def create
 @post = Post.create(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been saved"

  else

    render "new"
  end
end

def edit

end

def update

end

def destroy

end

private  
   def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id, :author_id)


end

end
```

Here is the html form:

```
<h1>Add New Post</h1>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %><br />
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]},     {:include_blank=> "Select One"}%><br />
 </p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit "Add Post" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And finally, the posts.rb file:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   #   Deprecated
   # attr_accessible :title, :body, :category_id, :author_id

   belongs_to :category
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
end
```

I am no Ruby expert, so my first thought is that the .save method requires additional arguments when using strong_parameters. Adding (post_params) to the save method didn't seem to have an effect, and I haven't been able to determine my issue using the Ruby documentation. I'd prefer to do this the "right" way, as opposed to just using the protected_attributes gem to use a deprecated (seemingly less secure) method.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to offer. When I get rich, I'll buy you a Ferrari*.

*May or may not be a Hot Wheels replica.

Eidt 2: Here is what the server throws out when attempting to POST to my database. It mentions a mass assignment error, but I thought I wasn't using them (strong params instead). Pardon my newbiness:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-11 18:28:13 -0700
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"9Ybchogw5u+sYbZOFYZtbJbXBkWC5EuCIZNUmAKyAQI=", "post"=>  {"title"=>"blahblahblah", "body"=>"blahblahblah", "category_id"=>"1"},   "commit"=>"Add Post"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Post: title, body,   category_id
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:18:in `create'
[1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
[1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "updated_at")  VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-03-12 01:28:13.990971"],   ["updated_at", "2015-03-12 01:28:13.990971"]]
[1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
[1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

And the index view. This is a training exercise, so it's just text, no styling:

```
<h1>Blog Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :etc, :etc)

Comment: Sorry, I had tried something but forgot to add that back in. The controller, including the def post_params, has been updated above.

Comment: ok, so now - go fill out the fields for a post, then watch your server logs, as you click "submit" and copy into your question the relevant section of the logs

Comment: Can you post the index view as well

Comment: Yes - it could have happily saved all the data, but your index view just might not be displaying any of it properly

Comment: It's saying something about a mass assignment error. Log is appended to the bottom. Index view will be appended ASAP.

Comment: Would I be better off starting over with new training lectures that are actually written for Rails 4, or is this not related to issues between Rails 3 and Rails 4 syntax?

Comment: protected_attributes is not your friend. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment your request/permit line in post_params and actually add the param names into it

```
def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id, :author_id)
end
```

That is why you are getting no data in your posts - because you aren't getting any data out of params anymore.

If the permit/require line is causing a different bug for you - we will help you fix that, but commenting out the security measure is not the way to solve it.

Comment: That was a typo on my part during copy paste. It has been fixed above. Thanks though :) I receive no errors, but the posts page just lists /posts/n/ as a title, where n is the current row in the posts table of my database. I wanted to upvote that anyway, but don't have enough reputation. :)

Comment: You've been very helpful and deserve the answer (especially since it was correct given the original question statement before I fixed the post_params line). I found the problem. Remember how I said I didn't want to use the protected_attributes gem? Apparently I forgot to remove it from my Gemfile and update my bundle when I decided to do things properly.